# Deezer API get full-length MP3

Tags: deezer

I use the **Deezer API** for my own music web application.The simple question is,how can *get the full length mp3* using this API.?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Deezer JavaScript SDK to be able to play the full tracks on your  website (assuming the user using your website have a premium Deezer account).

You can learn about how to use the SDK on Deezer's [Developers website](http://developers.deezer.com/sdk/javascript)